# Drools: is it required to upload all dependencies?

Tags: java, drools

I have a project that builds on a framework that uses drools. The model classes are already defined. I create the rules using drools guvnor and upload the jar with the model classes. But when I click on "Save and validate configuration" i get a bunch of warnings like this:

> Unable to find the class: sun.jdbc.rowset.CachedRowSet which is
>   required by: x.y.z.CustomClass. You may need to add more classes to the model.

This message seems to suggest that I have to upload the dependencies of the model classes as well. I tried that, but the transitive dependencies go on and on. I gave up at 20 jars. Maybe it is not necessary altogether and I made another mistake? Someone an idea what might went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally find my mistake. Each time I include another jar guvnor automatically add imports for all classes in the jar to the configuration. Deleting the superflous imports solves the transitive problem.